# How to save Media Player data on destroy of app?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I am currently working on a Music Player app. I want to implement a feature for this app like when the app is destroyed the music will stop playing I want to store the **current position** of music being played and its **details**.

And next time when a user comes back to the app they should see and able to resume the song from stopped position. This part is not the problem I cand do this

But How to store the details. **OnDestroy** method always not going to be called. So I cant write code to save these details there. And **onStop** is not the one needed here because eventhough onStop is called my app will be put in background and it will be playing song at background.

Since it is related to concept I am not posting any code. How to achieve this feature ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: first define `"when the app is destroyed"` - what do you exactly mean by that? just back button pressed?

Comment: @pskink when the user presses back button the app will be moved to the background I am using moveTaskToBack. so When the app is destroyed means when the user clears the app.

Comment: `"clears the app"`? sorry, this is exactly the same level of abstraction like `"when the app is destroyed"`

Comment: @pskink it means hitting the recent apps button or overview button (physical button of the device)  and swiping them to clear them. Got that name from here [official-button-names](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32697/what-is-the-offical-name-of-the-third-on-screen-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Use Case I would ignore all the life cycles and save it when the data changes. This approach will have any last state already stored before your app is killed. So when you switch your song / video you save your state then. And for every second your song / video plays you save the timestamp.

To save your values you can just use [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

That being said:

**For activities** `onPause()` would be the best time to store states, because an activity can be closed after that for various reasons. (mostly memory though). **For services** `onDestroy()` is your best option.

Comment: the data will be going to change every second show shall I create a saveCurrentSongDetails() and keep calling it every second on UI thread. Does it cost a performance issue?

Comment: It depends on how much data you are planning to save every second. Saving a string and a number is not going to make much of a difference in performance

Comment: K I will consider that one. Thanks

Comment: No worries. If this is the answer you were looking for, please accept it as an answer.